# OpenGL Output Not Displaying Correctly using Image for Texture

Tags: c++, image, opengl, graphics, output

so I got an image as a texture for a square, but the problem is that whenever I run the code I get this:

[image]

But when I take this line out:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, image1->sizeX, image1->sizeY, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image1->data);
```

Then I get this output (the white space is where I want to put the image as a texture):

[image: the white polygon]

Or if I change the third parameter to 5, then I get this output. But I know that the texture does display correctly when I run the code below, but the output is still like the first image at the top. How would I go about fixing the output so that it looks like the second image with the texture showing? Note that the texture DOES display fine with my code, you just cant see it becuase it's hidden becuase the whole output wont display properly.

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>   //for OpenCV 3.x  
#include <opencv/highgui.h>     //for OpenCV 3.x  
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define UpperBD 80
#define PI      3.1415926
#define Num_pts 10
using namespace std;
float Xe = 200.0f;//100
float Ye = 300.0f;
float Ze = 450.0f;
float Rho = sqrt(pow(Xe,2) + pow(Ye,2) + pow(Ze,2));
float D_focal = 100.0f; 
GLuint texture[2];

struct Image {

    unsigned long sizeX;
    unsigned long sizeY;
    char *data;
};
typedef struct Image Image;

#define checkImageWidth 64
#define checkImageHeight 64

GLubyte checkImage[checkImageWidth][checkImageHeight][3];
void makeCheckImage(void){

    int i, j, c;
    for (i = 0; i < checkImageWidth; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < checkImageHeight; j++) {
            c = ((((i&0x8)==0)^((j&0x8)==0)))*255;
            checkImage[i][j][0] = (GLubyte) c;
            checkImage[i][j][1] = (GLubyte) c;
            checkImage[i][j][2] = (GLubyte) c;
        }
    }
}
int ImageLoad(char *filename, Image *image) {

    FILE *file;

    unsigned long size; // size of the image in bytes.
    unsigned long i; // standard counter.
    unsigned short int planes; // number of planes in image (must be 1)
    unsigned short int bpp; // number of bits per pixel (must be 24)

    char temp; // temporary color storage for bgr-rgb conversion.
    // make sure the file is there.

    if ((file = fopen(filename, "rb"))==NULL){
        printf("File Not Found : %s\n",filename);
        return 0;
    }

    // seek through the bmp header, up to the width/height:
    fseek(file, 18, SEEK_CUR);

    // read the width
    if ((i = fread(&image->sizeX, 4, 1, file)) != 1) {
        printf("Error reading width from %s.\n", filename);
        return 0;
    }

    if ((i = fread(&image->sizeY, 4, 1, file)) != 1) {
        printf("Error reading height from %s.\n", filename);
        return 0;
    }

    size = image->sizeX * image->sizeY * 3;
    // read the planes
    if ((fread(&planes, 2, 1, file)) != 1) {
        printf("Error reading planes from %s.\n", filename);
        return 0;
    }
    if (planes != 1) {
        printf("Planes from %s is not 1: %u\n", filename, planes);
        return 0;
    }

    // read the bitsperpixel
    if ((i = fread(&bpp, 2, 1, file)) != 1) {
        printf("Error reading bpp from %s.\n", filename);
        return 0;
    }
    if (bpp != 24) {
        printf("Bpp from %s is not 24: %u\n", filename, bpp);
        return 0;
    }

    // seek past the rest of the bitmap header.
    fseek(file, 24, SEEK_CUR);
    // read the data.
    image->data = (char *) malloc(size);
    if (image->data == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating memory for color-corrected image data");
        return 0;
    }
    if ((i = fread(image->data, size, 1, file)) != 1) {
        printf("Error reading image data from %s.\n", filename);
        return 0;
    }
    for (i=0;i<size;i+=3) { // reverse all of the colors. (bgr -> rgb)
        temp = image->data[i];
        image->data[i] = image->data[i+2];
        image->data[i+2] = temp;
    }

    // we're done.
    return 1;
}

Image * loadTexture(){

    Image *image1;
    // allocate space for texture
    image1 = (Image *) malloc(sizeof(Image));
    if (image1 == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating space for image");
        exit(0);
    }

    if (!ImageLoad("g.bmp", image1)) {
        exit(1);
    }
    return image1;
}

void myinit(void)
//something in this function is making it not appear properly
{
    // glClearColor (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0);
    // glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    // glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

    Image *image1 = loadTexture();
    //  makeCheckImage();

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    // Create Texture
    glGenTextures(2, texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR); //scale linearly when image bigger than texture
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR); //scale linearly when image smalled than texture
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, image1->sizeX, image1->sizeY, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image1->data);
    //above line causing problem
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[1]);
    //  glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    // glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
    //  glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    //  glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);
    //  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, checkImageWidth, checkImageHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,&checkImage[0][0][0]);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    // glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
}

typedef struct {
    float X[UpperBD];
    float Y[UpperBD];
    float Z[UpperBD];
} pworld;

typedef struct {
    float X[UpperBD];
    float Y[UpperBD];
    float Z[UpperBD];
} pviewer;

typedef struct{
    float X[UpperBD];
    float Y[UpperBD];
} pperspective;

typedef struct{
    float X[UpperBD];
    float Y[UpperBD];
} pattern2DL;

typedef struct{
    float X[UpperBD];
    float Y[UpperBD];
} arrowpoint;

typedef struct {
    float r[UpperBD], g[UpperBD], b[UpperBD];
} pt_diffuse;

void mydisplay()
{
    // define x-y coordinate
    float p1x=-1.0f,  p1y= 0.0f;   
    float p2x= 1.0f,  p2y= 0.0f;
    float p3x= 0.0f,  p3y= 1.0f;
    float p4x= 0.0f,  p4y=-1.0f;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    pworld  world;
    pviewer viewer;
    pperspective perspective;
    pattern2DL letterL;
    arrowpoint arrow;

    //define the x-y-z world coordinate
    world.X[0] = 0.0;    world.Y[0] =  0.0;   world.Z[0] =  0.0;    // origin 
    world.X[1] = 50.0;   world.Y[1] =  0.0;   world.Z[1] =  0.0;    // x-axis
    world.X[2] = 0.0;    world.Y[2] =  50.0;  world.Z[2] =  0.0;    // y-axis   
    world.X[3] = 0.0;    world.Y[3] =  0.0;   world.Z[3] =  50.0;   // y-axis

    //define projection plane world coordinate , THIS IS THE SQUARE AROUND THE LETTERS
    world.X[4] = 60.0;   world.Y[4] = -50.0;   world.Z[4] =  0.0;    
    world.X[5] = 60.0;   world.Y[5] =  50.0;   world.Z[5] =  0.0;    // base line
    world.X[7] = 60.0;   world.Y[7] = -50.0;   world.Z[7] = 100.0;   // side bar
    world.X[6] = 60.0;   world.Y[6] =  50.0;   world.Z[6] =  100.0;    // side bar

    //define 2D pattern letter A
    letterL.X[0] = -10.0; letterL.Y[0] = 10.0;    
    letterL.X[1] = -15.0; letterL.Y[1] = 10.0; 
    letterL.X[2] = -20.0; letterL.Y[2] = 30.0;    
    letterL.X[3] = -40.0; letterL.Y[3] = 30.0;
    letterL.X[4] = -45.0; letterL.Y[4] = 10.0;  
    letterL.X[5] = -50.0; letterL.Y[5] = 10.0;
    letterL.X[6] = -37.0; letterL.Y[6] = 70.0;
    letterL.X[7] = -23.0; letterL.Y[7] = 70.0;
    letterL.X[8] = -25.0; letterL.Y[8] = 40.0;
    letterL.X[9] = -35.0; letterL.Y[9] = 40.0;
    letterL.X[10] = -30.0; letterL.Y[10] = 60.0;

    //letter B
    letterL.X[11] = 10.0; letterL.Y[11] = 10.0;    
    letterL.X[12] = 10.0; letterL.Y[12] = 70.0; 
    letterL.X[13] = 20.0; letterL.Y[13] = 10.0;    
    letterL.X[14] = 20.0; letterL.Y[14] = 70.0;

    letterL.X[15] = 20.0; letterL.Y[15] = 60.0;  
    letterL.X[16] = 20.0; letterL.Y[16] = 45.0;
    letterL.X[17] = 20.0; letterL.Y[17] = 35.0;
    letterL.X[18] = 20.0; letterL.Y[18] = 20.0;

    letterL.X[19] = 25.0; letterL.Y[19] = 58.0;
    letterL.X[20] = 27.0; letterL.Y[20] = 56.0;
    letterL.X[21] = 28.0; letterL.Y[21] = 52.0;
    letterL.X[22] = 27.0; letterL.Y[22] = 49.0;
    letterL.X[23] = 25.0; letterL.Y[23] = 47.0;

    letterL.X[24] = 25.0; letterL.Y[24] = 33.0;
    letterL.X[25] = 27.0; letterL.Y[25] = 31.0;
    letterL.X[26] = 28.0; letterL.Y[26] = 27.0;
    letterL.X[27] = 27.0; letterL.Y[27] = 24.0;
    letterL.X[28] = 25.0; letterL.Y[28] = 22.0;

    letterL.X[29] = 30.0; letterL.Y[29] = 65.0;
    letterL.X[30] = 34.0; letterL.Y[30] = 60.0;
    letterL.X[31] = 34.0; letterL.Y[31] = 50.0;
    letterL.X[32] = 30.0; letterL.Y[32] = 45.0;

    letterL.X[33] = 25.0; letterL.Y[33] = 40.0;

    letterL.X[34] = 30.0; letterL.Y[34] = 38.0;
    letterL.X[35] = 34.0; letterL.Y[35] = 30.0;
    letterL.X[36] = 34.0; letterL.Y[36] = 20.0;
    letterL.X[37] = 30.0; letterL.Y[37] = 15.0;

    arrow.X[0] = 0.0; arrow.Y[0] = 25.0;    
    arrow.X[1] = 0.0; arrow.Y[1] = 75.0; 
    arrow.X[2] = 60.0; arrow.Y[2] = 75.0;    
    arrow.X[3] = 60.0; arrow.Y[3] = 85.0;
    arrow.X[4] = 90.0; arrow.Y[4] = 50.0;  
    arrow.X[5] = 60.0; arrow.Y[5] = 15.0;
    arrow.X[6] = 60.0; arrow.Y[6] = 25.0;

    arrow.X[7] = 0.0; arrow.Y[7] = 25.0;    
    arrow.X[8] = 0.0; arrow.Y[8] = 75.0; 
    arrow.X[9] = 60.0; arrow.Y[9] = 75.0;    
    arrow.X[10] = 60.0; arrow.Y[10] = 85.0;
    arrow.X[11] = 90.0; arrow.Y[11] = 50.0;  
    arrow.X[12] = 60.0; arrow.Y[12] = 15.0;
    arrow.X[13] = 60.0; arrow.Y[13] = 25.0;

    //decoration
    for(int i = 0; i <= 37; i++)
    {
      world.X[8+i] = 60.0;
      world.Y[8+i] = letterL.X[i];
      world.Z[8+i] = letterL.Y[i];
    }
    //arrow
    for(int j = 0; j <= 6; j++)
    {
      world.X[46+j] = arrow.X[j]-50;//-50
      world.Y[46+j] = arrow.Y[j];
      world.Z[46+j] = 100.0;//CHANGE TO 150?
    }
    for(int k = 0; k <= 6; k++)
    {
      world.X[53+k] = arrow.X[k]-50;
      world.Y[53+k] = arrow.Y[k];
      world.Z[53+k] = 110.0;//CHANGE TO 150?
    }

    float sPheta = Ye / sqrt(pow(Xe,2) + pow(Ye,2));
    float cPheta = Xe / sqrt(pow(Xe,2) + pow(Ye,2));
    float sPhi = sqrt(pow(Xe,2) + pow(Ye,2)) / Rho;
    float cPhi = Ze / Rho;

    float xMin = 1000.0, xMax = -1000.0;
    float yMin = 1000.0, yMax = -1000.0;
    //47 is normal vector 46 is a, 45 is ps, 7 is top left box vertex
    //COMUTER SHADE OF FLOATING ARROW DUE NEXT WEEK

    world.X[60] = -200.0;   world.Y[60]=50.0;   world.Z[60]=200.0;//ps
    world.X[61] = 0.0;   world.Y[61]=0.0;   world.Z[61]=0.0;//vector a
    world.X[62] = 0.0;   world.Y[62]=0.0;   world.Z[62]=1.0;//VECTOR N

    float tmp = (world.X[62]*(world.X[61]-world.X[60]))
                +(world.Y[62]*(world.Y[61]-world.Y[60]))
                +(world.Z[62]*(world.Z[61]-world.Z[60]));
                cout << tmp;
    float lambda =  tmp/((world.X[62]*(world.X[60]-world.X[7]))
                +(world.Y[62]*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[7]))
                +(world.Z[62]*(world.Z[60]-world.Z[7])));
                cout << lambda;
    float lambda_2 = tmp/((world.X[62]*(world.X[60]-world.X[6]))//MAKE ARROW HIGHER, ABOVE PROJECTION PLANE SQUARE
                +(world.Y[62]*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[6]))
                +(world.Z[62]*(world.Z[60]-world.Z[6])));
                cout << lambda_2;
    world.X[63] = world.X[60]+lambda*(world.X[60]-world.X[7]);//interseciton point for p7, X COMP
    world.Y[63] = world.Y[60]+lambda*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[7]);//Y COMP
    world.Z[63] = 0.0;

    world.X[64] = world.X[60]+lambda_2*(world.X[60]-world.X[6]);//interseciton point for p7, X COMP
    world.Y[64] = world.Y[60]+lambda_2*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[6]);//Y COMP
    world.Z[64] = 0.0;


    //for arrow's shade, 46-52
    float lambda_arrow1 =  tmp/((world.X[62]*(world.X[60]-world.X[46]))
                +(world.Y[62]*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[46]))
                +(world.Z[62]*(world.Z[60]-world.Z[46])));

    float lambda_arrow2 = tmp/((world.X[62]*(world.X[60]-world.X[47]))//MAKE ARROW HIGHER, ABOVE PROJECTION PLANE SQUARE
                +(world.Y[62]*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[47]))
                +(world.Z[62]*(world.Z[60]-world.Z[47])));

    float lambda_arrow3 =  tmp/((world.X[62]*(world.X[60]-world.X[48]))
                            +(world.Y[62]*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[48]))
                            +(world.Z[62]*(world.Z[60]-world.Z[48])));

    float lambda_arrow4 =  tmp/((world.X[62]*(world.X[60]-world.X[49]))
                +(world.Y[62]*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[49]))
                +(world.Z[62]*(world.Z[60]-world.Z[49])));

    float lambda_arrow5 =  tmp/((world.X[62]*(world.X[60]-world.X[50]))
                +(world.Y[62]*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[50]))
                +(world.Z[62]*(world.Z[60]-world.Z[50])));

    float lambda_arrow6 =  tmp/((world.X[62]*(world.X[60]-world.X[51]))
                +(world.Y[62]*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[51]))
                +(world.Z[62]*(world.Z[60]-world.Z[51])));

    float lambda_arrow7 =  tmp/((world.X[62]*(world.X[60]-world.X[52]))
                +(world.Y[62]*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[52]))
                +(world.Z[62]*(world.Z[60]-world.Z[52])));

    world.X[65] = world.X[60]+lambda_arrow1*(world.X[60]-world.X[46]);//interseciton point for p7, X COMP
    world.Y[65] = world.Y[60]+lambda_arrow1*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[46]);//Y COMP
    world.Z[65] = 0.0;

    world.X[66] = world.X[60]+lambda_arrow2*(world.X[60]-world.X[47]);//interseciton point for p7, X COMP
    world.Y[66] = world.Y[60]+lambda_arrow2*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[47]);//Y COMP
    world.Z[66] = 0.0;

    world.X[67] = world.X[60]+lambda_arrow3*(world.X[60]-world.X[48]);//interseciton point for p7, X COMP
    world.Y[67] = world.Y[60]+lambda_arrow3*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[48]);//Y COMP
    world.Z[67] = 0.0;

    world.X[68] = world.X[60]+lambda_arrow4*(world.X[60]-world.X[49]);//interseciton point for p7, X COMP
    world.Y[68] = world.Y[60]+lambda_arrow4*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[49]);//Y COMP
    world.Z[68] = 0.0;

    world.X[69] = world.X[60]+lambda_arrow5*(world.X[60]-world.X[50]);//interseciton point for p7, X COMP
    world.Y[69] = world.Y[60]+lambda_arrow5*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[50]);//Y COMP
    world.Z[69] = 0.0;

    world.X[70] = world.X[60]+lambda_arrow6*(world.X[60]-world.X[51]);//interseciton point for p7, X COMP
    world.Y[70] = world.Y[60]+lambda_arrow6*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[51]);//Y COMP
    world.Z[70] = 0.0;

    world.X[71] = world.X[60]+lambda_arrow7*(world.X[60]-world.X[52]);//interseciton point for p7, X COMP
    world.Y[71] = world.Y[60]+lambda_arrow7*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[52]);//Y COMP
    world.Z[71] = 0.0;

  // -----------diffuse reflection-----------*
    pt_diffuse  diffuse;   //diffuse.r[3]

    //-------reflectivity coefficient-----------* 
    #define     Kdr     0.8
    #define     Kdg     0.0
    #define     Kdb     0.0

    // define additional pts to find diffuse reflection
    //world.X[49] = world.X[45] + lambda_2*(world.X[45] - world.X[6]);

    //--------compute distance------------------*//change 45 to 60!!!!!!
    float distance[UpperBD];
    for (int i=63; i<=71; i++) {
        distance[i] = sqrt(pow((world.X[i]-world.X[60]),2)+         //intersect pt p7
                            pow((world.Y[i]-world.Y[60]),2)+
                            pow((world.X[i]-world.X[60]),2) );
        //std::cout << "distance[i]  " << distance[i] << std::endl;
    } 

//    for (int i=4; i<=5; i++){
//    distance[i] = sqrt(pow((world.X[i]-world.X[60]),2)+         //pt p4 of projection plane
//                        pow((world.Y[i]-world.Y[60]),2)+
//                        pow((world.X[i]-world.X[60]),2) );
//    //std::cout << "distance[i]  " << distance[i] << std::endl;
//    }


    //--------compute angle---------------------*
    float angle[UpperBD], tmp_dotProd[UpperBD], tmp_mag_dotProd[UpperBD]; 

    for (int i=63; i<=71; i++){

        tmp_dotProd[i] = world.Z[i]-world.X[60]; 
        std::cout << " tmp_dotProd[i]  " <<  tmp_dotProd[i] << std::endl;

        tmp_mag_dotProd[i] = sqrt(pow((world.X[i]-world.X[60]),2)+         //[45] pt light source 
                            pow((world.Y[i]-world.Y[60]),2)+
                            pow((world.Z[i]-world.Z[60]),2) );
        std::cout << " tmp_mag_dotProd[i]  1 " <<  tmp_mag_dotProd[i] << std::endl;

        angle[i] = tmp_dotProd[i]/ tmp_mag_dotProd[i]; 
        std::cout << "angle[i]  " << angle[i] << std::endl;

        //compute color intensity
        diffuse.r[i] = Kdr *  angle[i] /  pow(distance[i],2) ;
        diffuse.g[i] = Kdg *  angle[i] /  pow(distance[i],2) ;
        diffuse.b[i] = Kdb *  angle[i] /  pow(distance[i],2) ;
    }

//   for (int i=4; i<=5; i++){
//
//    tmp_dotProd[i] = world.Z[i]-world.X[45]; 
//    std::cout << " tmp_dotProd[i]  " <<  tmp_dotProd[i] << std::endl;
//
//    tmp_mag_dotProd[i] = sqrt(pow((world.X[i]-world.X[45]),2)+         //[45] pt light source 
//                        pow((world.Y[i]-world.Y[45]),2)+
//                        pow((world.Z[i]-world.Z[45]),2) );
//    std::cout << " tmp_mag_dotProd[i]  1 " <<  tmp_mag_dotProd[i] << std::endl;
//
//    angle[i] = tmp_dotProd[i]/ tmp_mag_dotProd[i]; 
//    std::cout << "angle[i]  " << angle[i] << std::endl;
//
//    //compute color intensity
//    diffuse.r[i] = Kdr *  angle[i] /  pow(distance[i],2) ;
//    diffuse.g[i] = Kdg *  angle[i] /  pow(distance[i],2) ;
//    diffuse.b[i] = Kdb *  angle[i] /  pow(distance[i],2) ;
//
//    //std::cout << "diffuse.r[i]  " << diffuse.r[i] << std::endl;
//    //std::cout << "diffuse.g[i]  " << diffuse.g[i] << std::endl;
//    }
//
    for(int i = 0; i < UpperBD; i++)
    {
      viewer.X[i] = -sPheta * world.X[i] + cPheta * world.Y[i];
      viewer.Y[i] = -cPheta * cPhi * world.X[i] 
               - cPhi * sPheta * world.Y[i]
               + sPhi * world.Z[i];
      viewer.Z[i] = -sPhi * cPheta * world.X[i]
               - sPhi * cPheta * world.Y[i]
               -cPheta * world.Z[i] + Rho;
              // cout << i;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= UpperBD; i++)
    {
        perspective.X[i] = D_focal * viewer.X[i] / viewer.Z[i] ;
        perspective.Y[i] = D_focal * viewer.Y[i] / viewer.Z[i] ;
        if (perspective.X[i] > xMax) xMax = perspective.X[i];
        if (perspective.X[i] < xMin) xMin = perspective.X[i];
        if (perspective.Y[i] > yMax) yMax = perspective.Y[i];
        if (perspective.Y[i] < yMin) yMin = perspective.Y[i]; 
      /////*
      //std::cout << "xMin " << xMin << std::endl;
      //  std::cout << "xMax " << xMax << std::endl;
      //  std::cout << "yMin " << yMin << std::endl;
      //  std::cout << "yMax " << yMax << std::endl;
      //*/
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= UpperBD; i++)
    {
        if ((xMax-xMin) != 0) perspective.X[i] = perspective.X[i]/(xMax-xMin);
        if ((yMax-yMin) != 0) perspective.Y[i] = perspective.Y[i]/(yMax-yMin);
        std::cout << i << perspective.X[i] << perspective.Y[i] << std::endl;
    }
    glViewport(0,0,1550,1250);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();


    glBegin(GL_LINES);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[0],perspective.Y[0]); 
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[1],perspective.Y[1]);
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[0],perspective.Y[0]); 
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[2],perspective.Y[2]);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[0],perspective.Y[0]); 
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[3],perspective.Y[3]);

    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);  // projection plane , square
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[4],perspective.Y[4]); 
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[5],perspective.Y[5]);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[4],perspective.Y[4]); 
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[7],perspective.Y[7]);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[5],perspective.Y[5]); 
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[6],perspective.Y[6]);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[6],perspective.Y[6]); 
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[7],perspective.Y[7]);
    glEnd();

    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);  // LETTER A STARTS HERE
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[13],perspective.Y[13]);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[12],perspective.Y[12]);

    glVertex2f(perspective.X[11],perspective.Y[11]);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[12],perspective.Y[12]);

    glVertex2f(perspective.X[14],perspective.Y[14]);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[13],perspective.Y[13]);

    glVertex2f(perspective.X[18],perspective.Y[18]);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[17],perspective.Y[17]);

    glVertex2f(perspective.X[11],perspective.Y[11]);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[17],perspective.Y[17]);

    glVertex2f(perspective.X[18],perspective.Y[18]);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[14],perspective.Y[14]);

    glEnd();
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); 
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    glVertex2f(perspective.X[8],perspective.Y[8]);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[15],perspective.Y[15]);

    glVertex2f(perspective.X[14],perspective.Y[14]);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[15],perspective.Y[15]);

    glVertex2f(perspective.X[14],perspective.Y[14]);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[18],perspective.Y[18]);

    glVertex2f(perspective.X[16],perspective.Y[16]);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[18],perspective.Y[18]);

    glVertex2f(perspective.X[16],perspective.Y[16]);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[10],perspective.Y[10]);

    glVertex2f(perspective.X[9],perspective.Y[9]);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[10],perspective.Y[10]);

    glVertex2f(perspective.X[8],perspective.Y[8]);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[9],perspective.Y[9]);


    glEnd();
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); 
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    glVertex2f(perspective.X[16],perspective.Y[16]);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[17],perspective.Y[17]);
    //etc...


    glEnd();
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);  //LETTER B STARTS HERE
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    glVertex2f(perspective.X[19],perspective.Y[19]);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[20],perspective.Y[20]);

    //etc...

    glEnd();
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    //     
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[23],perspective.Y[23]);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[24],perspective.Y[24]);

    glVertex2f(perspective.X[25],perspective.Y[25]);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[26],perspective.Y[26]);

    glEnd();
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); 
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    glVertex2f(perspective.X[27],perspective.Y[27]);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[28],perspective.Y[28]);

    //etc...

    glEnd();
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); 
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    glVertex2f(perspective.X[29],perspective.Y[29]);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[30],perspective.Y[30]);
    //etc...

    glEnd();
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); 
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    glVertex2f(perspective.X[24],perspective.Y[24]);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[41],perspective.Y[41]);

    //etc...

    glEnd();
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);


    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);//3D arrow starts here

    glVertex2f(perspective.X[46],perspective.Y[46]);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[47],perspective.Y[47]);

    //etc...

    glEnd();    //end arrow

    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);

    glVertex2f(perspective.X[63],perspective.Y[63]);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[64],perspective.Y[64]);
    //etc...

    glEnd();    //end arrow

    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    //arrow shadow

    glVertex2f(perspective.X[65],perspective.Y[65]);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[66],perspective.Y[66]);
    //etc...

    glEnd();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[1]);

    //  glutSolidTeapot(0.1);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
    glColor4f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[4],perspective.Y[4]); 
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[5],perspective.Y[5]);
    glTexCoord2f(0.1, 0.0);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[4],perspective.Y[4]); 
    glTexCoord2f(0.1, 0.1);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[7],perspective.Y[7]);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.1);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[5],perspective.Y[5]); 
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[6],perspective.Y[6]);
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[6],perspective.Y[6]); 
    glVertex2f(perspective.X[7],perspective.Y[7]);
    glEnd();

    glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );

    //glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    #define     display_scaling        200000.0
    #define     display_shifting    0.2
    for (int i=63; i<=71; i++) {
        float r, g, b;
        r = display_scaling*diffuse.r[i]+display_shifting;
        //r = display_scaling*diffuse.r[i];
        g = diffuse.g[i]; b = diffuse.b[i] ;
        glColor3f(r, g, b);
        std::cout << "display_scaling*diffuse.r[i]  " << r << std::endl;
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2f(perspective.X[i],perspective.Y[i]);
        glVertex2f(perspective.X[i]+0.1,perspective.Y[i]);
        glVertex2f(perspective.X[i]+0.1,perspective.Y[i]+0.1);
        glVertex2f(perspective.X[i],perspective.Y[i]+0.1);
        glEnd();
    }

    gluPerspective(45.0,0.5,1.0,60.0);
    gluOrtho2D(5, 10, 0.0, 10);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glFlush();
    //sleep(5);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("b.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB );
    glutInitWindowSize(900, 1000);
    glutCreateWindow("lab");

    //imshow( "lab", image );  
    glutDisplayFunc(mydisplay);
    myinit();
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Your code is C++, not C.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tag that, thanks.

Comment: Just use [stb image](https://github.com/nothings/stb) or OpenImageIO instead of writing your own image reader function. Writing robust image reader functions is hard. And skimming over your code it looks like you've followed some ill conceived tutorial or code that's roaming the web and just won't die; it's easily recognizable by that the first thing it does is skipping over the start of the file the size of a DIB header; it's infuriating to see that.

Comment: Read [How to load a bmp on GLUT to use it as a texture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518111/how-to-load-a-bmp-on-glut-to-use-it-as-a-texture/50641676#50641676)

Comment: Yeah so I did try @Rabbid76 answer, but now I get a blank screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` has to be removed from `myinit`, because it is done immediately before the object with the texture is drawn.
Further use the [STB library](https://stb.handmade.network/), which can be found at [GitHub - nothings/stb](https://github.com/nothings/stb) to load the bitmap:

```
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb_image.h>
```

```
void myinit(void)
{
      glGenTextures(2, texture);

      int cx, cy, ch;
      stbi_uc *img = stbi_load("g.bmp", &cx, &cy, &ch, 3);
      if (!img)
        return;

      glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);     
      glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
      glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
      glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR); 
      glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, cx, cy, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
      stbi_image_free( img );

      // ....
}
```

---

The number of vertex coordinates is `UpperBD`, so the maximum index is `UpperBD-1` or `< UpperBD`, but not `<= UpperBD`.

Change (2 times):

<s>`for(int i = 0; i <= UpperBD; i++)`</s>
`for(int i = 0; i < UpperBD; i++)`

---

`gluPerspective` and `gluOrtho2D` at once makes no sense at all.

Init the projection matrix and the model view matrix at the begin of each frame in `mydisplay`:

```
void mydisplay()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45.0,0.5,1.0,60.0);
    //gluOrtho2D(5, 10, 0.0, 10);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    .....
}
```

---

When the vertex coordinate is set by [`glVertex`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertex.xml) the current texture coordinates, and is associated with the vertex coordinate. This means [`glTexCoord`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexCoord.xml) has to be dine before [`glVertex`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertex.xml). A [`GL_QUAD`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Quads) primitive consitis of 4 vertices and each vertex coordinate needs its own texture coordinate:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
glColor4f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
glVertex2f(perspective.X[4],perspective.Y[4]);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);
glVertex2f(perspective.X[5],perspective.Y[5]);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);
glVertex2f(perspective.X[6],perspective.Y[6]);
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
glVertex2f(perspective.X[7],perspective.Y[7]);
glEnd();
```

Comment: Ok thanks but now when I run the code I get a blank black screen. Nothing shows up.

Comment: Nevermind now there is no blank screen but now the texture is still white

Comment: Actually I think that is the image but it's not displaying properly on the whitespace texture.

Comment: thanks for that. So the image is displaying, but the problem is its too zoomed in. How would I zoom out so that the whole image can display on the texture whitespace?

Comment: ok I see, now it works! Thank you so much, I spent hours trying to get this to work! Now it works, thanks again.